# Large data binding to Kendo Combo Box

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui

When I am trying to bind some 5000+ records to Kendo Combobox, it giving error but when it use .Take(1000) the error goes. I guess the problem is with the huge data. Following is the Code:
**Index.cshtml :**

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
    .Name("RuleNames")
    .DataTextField("RuleName")
    .DataValueField("RuleID")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 400px" })
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    .Placeholder(@UI.SelectDropDownText)
    .AutoBind(true)
    .MinLength(3)
    .DataSource(source => source.Read(read =>  read.Action("ActionName", "Controller")))
```

**Controller** :

```
public virtual JsonResult RuleDetailsJsonObject()
{
    var commissionsActFacade = new CommissionServiceFacade(this.commissionManager);
    List<CommissionViewModel> ruleInfo = commissionsActFacade.GetProductRules(string.Empty);
    return this.Json(ruleInfo.Select(o => new CommissionsACTViewModel {
        RuleID = o.ProductRuleID"
    }),   
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Error**
javascript runtime Error: Object doesn't supportproperty or method 'slice'.

Comment: That error uses to happen when the server returns something that is not a correct JSON. Did you try invoking the service from your browser and checking that it actually is a JSON?

Comment: @OneBai : I dint get you Sir.. Please elaborate

Comment: Can you invoke the service (the code that run into the server) from the browser by typing some URL on it? If so, check that the return value contains data and valid data. What I'm trying is debugging the value received by the browser from the Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you hit the [MaxJsonLength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config) problem, once you increase it also I would also suggest you to project your collection into anonymous object instead of that ViewModel CommissionsACTViewModel , since it main contain some fields which will be serialized but are not needed, however they increase the size of the JSON.

Comment: U said true. All the properties in View Model were getting serialized unnecessarily. So, I removed the ViewModel name and made it anonymous.